# Change div things in other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I used the code below to make a change in div of the page of this code file:

```
HtmlGenericControl divTest = Page.FindControl("test") as HtmlGenericControl;   
divTeste.InnerText = "tested";
```

But now, I want to change another page. Ex.: default.aspx code behind changes a div inner text in the test.aspx ...

The code above isn't appropriated. I want permanent changes. What code should be?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how ASP.NET works. [Introduction to ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4468/Beginners-Introduction-to-ASP-NET)

If you are on Default.aspx and then wont to move to Test.aspx you can use values from Default.aspx in Test.aspx however you can't just change different pages from the page you are on. (Actually it is possible by writing data to a database and then later accessing that data on the page you want to change but for your example I don't believe you are looking for something like that)

The closest to your example I can think of is using a Query string.

**Default.aspx Markup**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**Default.aspx Code behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Test.aspx?DivMSG=Hello");
}
```

**Test.aspx Markup**

```
<div id="MyTestDiv" runat="server">

</div>
```

**Test.aspx Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MyTestDiv.InnerText = Request.QueryString["DivMSG"];
    }
}
```

**Update:**

One way to make it permanent is to write it to a database. A quick example but you need to do the database code

**Default.aspx Markup**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**Default.aspx Code behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string messageToWriteToTestDiv = TextBox1.Text;

    // Code: to write messageToWriteToTestDiv to the database
}
```

**Test.aspx Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string myMessage = "";

        // Code: string myMessage = Get Message from Database to write to div

        MyTestDiv.InnerText = myMessage;
    }
}
```

**Test.aspx Markup**

```
<div id="MyTestDiv" runat="server">

</div>
```